# Sorting list of VirtualPages on a field from its Page

Tags: silverstripe

I have an `AreaPage` with `$many_many` `VirtualPage`s:

```php
class AreaPage extends Page {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $many_many = [
        'RelatedVirtualPages'  => 'VirtualPage'
    ];

    // ...

}
```

The `RelatedVirtualPages` are copying content from `ContentPage`s:

```php
class ContentPage extends Page {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $db = [
        'Highlighted' => 'Boolean'
    ];

    // ...

}
```

What's the best way to sort `RelatedVirtualPages` on the `Highlighted` db field of the `ContentPage` that it's copying?

Comment: Shouldn't 'RelatedVirtualPages'  => 'VirtualPages' be 'RelatedVirtualPages'  => 'VirtualPage' ?

Comment: Yes, you're right :-) Updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual Pages could be pointed at pages of different types and there is no enforcement that all of those pages are `ContentPages`, or at least pages that have a `Hightlighted` db field.  You can ensure this manually when you create your `SiteTree`, but users could come along and screw it up so keep this in mind.

Here is some psuedo-code that might help you get started.  It assumes that all virtual pages are `ContentPages`.  If you will have multiple types of `VirtualPages` referenced by an `AreaPage` then this is probably not sufficient.

```
$virtualPages = $myAreaPage->RelatedVirtualPages();
$contentSourcePages = ContentPage::get()->byIDs($virtualPage->column('CopyContentFromID'));
$sortedSourcePages = $contentSourcePages->sort('Highlighted','ASC');
```

You possibly could also use an `innerJoin`, but then you have to deal with _Live tables and possibly multiple page tables (again if not just using `ContentPage` as `VirtualPage`) which could lead to some complicated scenarios.

**Update**

So, to summarize in my own words, you need a list of the `VirtualContentPages` linked to a specific `AreaPage` sorted on the `Highlighted` field from the `ContentPage` that each `VirtualContentPage` links to.  If this summary is accurate, would this work:

```
$sortedVirtualPages = $myAreaPage->RelatedVirtualPages()
 ->innerJoin('ContentPage', '"ContentPage"."ID" = "VirtualContentPage"."CopyContentFromID"')
 ->sort('Highlighted DESC');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing me in a direction. The pseudo code gives me a sorted list of the `ContentPage`s, but I need a list of the actual `VirtualPage`s. I'm thinking doing something like getting the `VirtualPage`s, then iterating over them, adding a `Highlighted` property to each object (w/o writing, copying value from the page being copied), then adding them to an ArrayList, then sorting the ArrayList on `Highlighted`. Thoughts?

Comment: As for enforcing page type to be `ContentPage` - I left out these parts in favor of providing a simple demonstration of the problem. In the actual code this is handled by the fact that I'm extending VirtualPage (`VirtualContentPage`, `[VCP]`), and `VCP` can only exist under `AreaPage`, which can only host `VCP` and `ContentPage`. If an editor changes `VCP` to copy content from say an `AreaPage`, a validation error will be thrown (~`AreaPage` is not allowed as a child of `AreaPage`).

Comment: Thanks! Your summary is accurate and the inner join solution is definitely the most efficient and clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a very clean method, but did find two ways to achieve this. The function goes in the class `AreaPage`
**First**

```
public function getRelatedVirtualPages()
{

    $items = $this->getManyManyComponents('RelatedVirtualPages');

    $highlighted = $items->filterByCallback(function($record, $list) {
        if($record->CopyContentFrom() instanceOf ContentPage) {
            //return ! $record->CopyContentFrom()->Highlighted; // ASC
            return $record->CopyContentFrom()->Highlighted; // DESC
        }
    });

    $highlighted->merge($items);
    $highlighted->removeDuplicates();

    return $highlighted;
}
```

**Second (the method you described in the comments)**

```
public function getRelatedVirtualPages()
{
    $items = $this->getManyManyComponents('RelatedVirtualPages');

    $arrayList = new ArrayList();

    foreach($items as $virtualPage) 
    {
        if($virtualPage->CopyContentFrom() instanceOf ContentPage) {
            $virtualPage->Highlighted = $virtualPage->CopyContentFrom()->Highlighted;
            $arrayList->push($virtualPage);
        }
    }

    $arrayList = $arrayList->sort('Highlighted DESC');

    return $arrayList;
}
```

I'm not very proud of any of these solutions, but I believe they do fit your criteria.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting solution 1. I'd go for it if it wasn't for the fact that I need to sort on another field as well, which is a `Date` and not a `Boolean`. Solution 2. is what I went for first, but felt it was expensive in terms of performance - querying the database for each iteration (?). I modified it a bit with inspiration from AlphaCactus to only run two queries and save away the results. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing, which I think works:

```php
/**
 * @return ArrayList
 */
public function VirtualPages()
{

    $result       = [];
    $virtualPages = $this->RelatedVirtualPages();
    $contentPages = ContentPage::get()
        ->byIDs($virtualPages->column('CopyContentFromID'))
        ->map('ID', 'Highlighted')
        ->toArray();

    foreach($virtualPages as $virtualPage) {
        $highlighted = $contentPages[$virtualPage->CopyContentFromID];
        $virtualPage->Highlighted =  $highlighted;
        $result[] = $virtualPage;
    }

    return ArrayList::create(
        $result
    );

}
```

And then it's sortable like so:

```php
$areaPage->VirtualPages()->sort('Highlighted DESC');
```

Thank you for all the answers and pointers. I'll wait a bit before marking any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do

```
//just get one areapage
$AreaPageItem = AreaPage::get()->First();

//now get the RelatedVirtualPages sorted
$related_pages = $AreaPageItem->RelatedVirtualPages()->sort("Highlighted","ASC");
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work since the `Highlighted` column does not exist on VirtualPage and will cause a MySQL error.